# place a value of a model in a select list

Tags: cakephp, selectlist

I want to place fields from a model in a select list.
I have this code..

brand.php & car.php models

```
 class Brand extends AppModel{ 
  var $name = 'Brand'; 
  var $hasMany = 'Car'; 
 }
 <?php   
 class Car extends AppModel{ 
  var $name = 'Car'; 
  var $belongsTo = 'Brand'; 
 } 
 ?>
```

the controller

```
   <?php 
   class CarsController extends AppController{
   var $name = 'Cars';
   function index(){
   $this->set('id', $this->Car->find('all'));
   }
   }
  ?>
```

this is the view index.ctp

```
<?php   
echo $form->create('Search'); 
foreach($id as $options){ 
     echo $options['Brand']['name']."<br>";  // it works
$values = array(); 
$values[] = $options['Brand']['name']; // doesnt work!

} 
echo $this->Form->select('one', $values); // the values for selects just the last one
echo $form->end('search'); 
?>
```

So how place the fields and id for the option values from the Brand.php model in the select list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$this->set('brands', $this->Car->Brand->find('list'));
```

In your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('brand_id');
```

Cake will automagically link the $brands view var to the brand_id fields options list.

Comment: thanks...it works!! //in my controller $brands = $this->Car->Brand->find('list'));
$this->set('id', $brands); //then in my view echo $this->Form->select('BrandName', $id);

Answer (score 2):

Change your `find('all')` call to a `find('list')` call and call it on the Brand model.

This will get you an associative array with `id` => `displayField` of all the `Brand` records. You can modify with field is the display field by specifying it in the model `var $displayField = 'my_field';`